# EuropeCV-Class tweak german translation?

Tags: europecv

So i want to create a new CV. I use the following basic code:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,narrow,nologo,nobranding,german]{europecv}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}

\ecvpersonalinfo

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

So instead of: "Name / Surname" the result "Nachname(n) / Vorname(n)" gets displayed. This looks very machine-made. I would prefer: "Vorname Nachname".

I've read the class-documentation on CTAN, but unfortunately i found nothing so far. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translations are given in the various `.def` files, the one for German is `ecvde.def`. In that file you find the following line:

```
\def\ecv@namekey{\ecv@utf{Nachname(n) / Vorname(n)}}
```

You can change the translation by redefining this command in your own `.tex` file after the package is loaded. Because the line contains `@` symbols you need to surround the redefinition with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,narrow,nologo,nobranding,german]{europecv}
\makeatletter
\def\ecv@namekey{\ecv@utf{Vorname Nachname}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}

\ecvpersonalinfo

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]